# installation and using MAFFT in windows for python Bio.Align.Application MafftCommandline

Tags: python, alignment, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to install and use mafft multiple sequence alignment algorithm in windows. I read the mafft docs and it says I either can extract the mafft-win zip file or install it on a Linux subsystem. I went through the former procedure and added the path to my environment variable settings. Now I can access mafft from cmd but biopython MafftCommandline still gives me error that it can't recognize mafft. I don't think the later procedure will solve the problem because it is not on windows but on the subsystem and can't access it from a jupyter notebook from anaconda in windows either! 
I've used mafft in my ubuntu system and it works fine but I need it to work on windows, because I want to run my python code in windows. I appreciate it if anyone could give me some hints or a method to solve this problem.

---

My workaround for this issue:
I transferred all my development environment into the windows subsystem for Linux, and now I have access to MAFFT in Linux through Conda. wsl is the best option for people who need to stay in the windows environment but need to access Linux

Comment: You can always access mafft using the os or subprocess libraries instead of biopython. I would expect the behavior to be similar. Example: subprocess.check_output("/full/path/to/mafft input.fasta", shell=True)

Comment: I'm using it along with several other sub-packages in the biopython to making a command-line app for a specific purpose. therefore, It would be much better to access it through biopython.

Answer (score 0):

At a wild guess it is possible MAFFT is not within the `anaconda3` bin, viz. ~/anaconda3/bin/mafft.

It should work even if it is correctly visible to the system, however you could just download it specifically via conda, viz.

```
anaconda-navigator
```

Looking at the  GUI image is below, where you see "Installed", there is a drop down menu for "Installed" and check that mafft is there. Otherwise simply go to `Not installed` open the "channels" tab and add `bioconda` and update, then update the index. mafft should now appear in the dropdown menu "Not installed".

[image: Anaconda navigator]

**General info**

anaconda-navigator works great remotely via X11 if you have Anaconda loaded on a remote cluster/server.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried to install it through conda as you said but neither the 'conda install -c bioconda mafft' nor using the GUI instruction worked. for the former method, it says there is no mafft in the channels and the latter doesn't have mafft in the bioconda channel!

Comment: I also checked the conda website and in the 'conda install' section there is just 'linux-64' and 'osx-64' but no windows. Therefore, I think the problem is using windows. I might have to use a virtual machine with ubuntu to temporarily solve the problem.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I already have anaconda on my windows 10 system, I said the mafft package in conda doesn't support windows. check the following link: https://anaconda.org/bioconda/mafft